# Error encountered while declaring hex color type : "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represe ts(2590)"

Tags: typescript

Here is my type declaration:

```js
type Hex = '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'A'|'B'|'C'|'D'|'E'|'F'|'a'|'b'|'c'|'d'|'e'|'f';
// ↓↓ Error: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent
type HexColor = `#${Hex}${Hex}${Hex}${Hex}${Hex}${Hex}`;
```

Typescript version: 5.2.2.

Playground link:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhAeUC8UDkAGVAfVBGbqATAQMwEAsBArAQGwEDsBAHAQJwECCBAQgQMIEAIgQCiBAGIEAhgQBGBAMYEAJgQgEAZqgDcAKFCRYCfgHsANqYBOyKAAMAxABIA3nHgBfV+69uEvn29-IM87HSA

---

---

Thanks to @jcalz for his answer, I made a slight tweak based on the answer he provided and this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhAeUC8UDkAGVUA+aCMWuqATIWgMxmoAsVArFQGxUDsVAHFQJxUCCVAISoBhKgBEqAUSoAxKgEMqAIyoBjKgBMqEKgDNUAbgBQR0JFgJhAewA2VgE4AeACpQEwCADsNAZyg-gewBLTwBzABooABk3eA9vP3lPEABtAF1kKHTI3lj4339AkNDMgCJSgD5kIyha6JTSmy9Q4AALUoz3LwLGKAB+KFyALhq61y6EqAADABIAbxDdCHsoGQBfecXlqAAlNan+i3hrOycdyJT0SIA6W6i0yNm53g25mTzuvzhEAfehqHQ+wqo1q-2+JwcjnKFyuUFu13uj3mL3QUwqxhMpnA0Bg8h8rXBtkh4zin0KwTCVRQIKgJPyfimAGJNp4lisYPtDkz5oTTo4YBVOf9PBAAG7LDFGVRWTwBKCtSxElYoFwfSYBCmhCoACla-zpZNx+N5xKqA1cYLxBMVfOcFQAlMgqq1JdLZcAoCA8JkFccldrSoz0HhiORqHRSvbjG65SBiD6bQ4A4zeAJhGJJDJI9GZbHyAm-adk+h0LpdCXsyYYx7PN6UL6IfYA6n05Js1AAPQdwb2UIAVwAtl4PVZdFAzNBUKUWxnSlggn5PFYPXifEFQp55EomuOrFAwPJ7PIhx4VqPx9i0NO0xn0HPrlLczX4-XE03r62ZLx212e-2h54I5jhOV4zpm37zouy5QKu66btu0DAHuB5Hie2zniBU5gVmqAPtWUCePmr6FkmpTBsQADiMhtlGnbdrwvaDsOUAYZeU7kVRbaQQR0GwRuW47kh+6HseECnixwFsWRIboNR96Pu6BHUAWjYBgA7q08geOK9g-vRjEAUBF7mFOGlaWKyxzlAC48SuPhrvxCG7sJqFiehkkmWR6DyOgEB3rhJhAA) is the final result.

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way.  The closest you can get is to write a generic type that acts like a constraint, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaZknm).  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the example you provided. It solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: I think it would be very useful for future readers if we edited the question to something like *"How to declare a Hex Color type?"* and add @jcalz's answer.

Comment: You can also find some information how to accomplish it in my [blog](https://catchts.com/hex-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding directly to `HexColor`.  [Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) can only hold up to about 100,000 members.  It's rarely possible to represent "a union of all possible combinations of" something without running into that limit.  A string of three `Hex` characters can be represented as a union (22<sup>3</sup> < 11,000), but strings of four or more `Hex` characters cannot (22<sup>4</sup> > 200,000).

There has long been a feature request to support *regular-expression validated string types* in TypeScript; the current open issue is at [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160).  If that is ever implemented, you should be able to represent `HexColor` that way. But for now this is not part of the language, so you'll need another approach.

For now, the closest you can get is to give up on a specific `HexColor` type, and instead write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `HexColor<T>` type which acts like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) input `T`.  The goal is that `T extends HexColor<T>` if and only if `T` would have been a valid `HexColor`. Additionally, it's useful to make it so that if `T` is *not* a valid `HexColor`, then `HexColor<T>` *is* a valid `HexColor` which is "close" to `T`, so that users get somewhat decipherable error messages.  Anyway, you'd use `HexColor<T>` to write a generic helper function `hexColor()` which only accepts a valid hex color input, and just returns its input.  So instead of `const y: HexColor = "012345"`, you'd write `const y = hexColor("012345")`.  So the general approach is something like

```
type HexColor<T> = ⋯;
const hexColor = <T extends HexColor<T>>(h: T) => h;
const y = hexColor("012345"); // okay
const n = hexColor("012GFE"); // error, "021GFE" is not "0210FE"
```

Here's one way to write `HexColor<T>`, which always produces a six-character string literal whose characters are the corresponding `Hex` character from `T` if there is one, or `"0"` otherwise.  So `"021GFE"` becomes `"0210FE"` (because `"G"` is inavlid), and `"ABCDE"` becomes `"ABCDE0"` (because the string is too short), and `"ABCDEFA"` becomes `"ABCDEF"` (because the string is too long):

```
type HexColor<T extends string, L extends any[] = [], A extends string = ""> =
    L["length"] extends 6 ? A :
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? HexColor<R, [0, ...L], `${A}${F extends Hex ? F : 0}`>
    : HexColor<"", [0, ...L], `${A}0`>;
```

This is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types).  The `L` type parameter is an accumulator representing a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) whose length is the same as the number of characters processed so far.  And the `A` type parameter is an accumulator representing the accumulated output so far.  (Ideally we'd only use `A`, but you can't directly ask TypeScript how long a string literal type is, whereas you *can* do it for tuple types.  So instead of `A["length"]` I'm using `L["length"]`.)

If `L` is `6` then we've processed 6 characters and we just return the accumulated output `A`.  Otherwise, we split `T` into the first character `F` and the rest of the string `R` (using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) and [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)) and recurse.  The next step uses `R` in place of `T`, a tuple one element longer than `L` in place of `L`, and for the accumulated output we append to `A` a single character.  If `F` is a valid `Hex` then we append `F`.  Otherwise we append `"0"`.  Oh and if we cannot split `T` because it's empty, then we still recurse, but with an empty string `""` in place of `T` and with `"0"` as the appended character.

You can verify that it behaves as described above.

Next, the `hexColor` helper function is slightly different from what was written above:

```
const hexColor = <T extends string>(
  h: T extends HexColor<T> ? T : HexColor<T>) => h;
```

That's because you can't write `T extends HexColor<T>` without getting a circularity error.  So we just constrain `T` to `string` and then apply `HexColor<T>` inside the type of `h`.  Again, it would be nice to write `<T extends string>(h: HexColor<T>) => h`, but this doesn't infer string literal types for `h`.  The weird `T extends HexColor<T> ? T : HexColor<T>` conditional type has the desired effect of allowing the compiler to infer a string literal type for `T`, compare it to `HexColor<T>`, and then evaluate to either `T` or `HexColor<T>` depending on whether the comparison succeeds or fails.  It's ugly/weird but it's the only way I've found that works in practice.

Okay, let's test it:

```
const y1 = hexColor("012345"); // okay
const y2 = hexColor("ABCDEF"); // okay
const y3 = hexColor("00ff00"); // okay

const n1 = hexColor("ABCDE"); // error!
// Argument of type '"ABCDE"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"ABCDE0"'.
const n2 = hexColor("ABCDEFA"); // error!
// Argument of type '"ABCDEFA"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"ABCDEF"'.
const n3 = hexColor("012GFE"); // error!
// Argument of type '"012GFE"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"0120FE"'.
const n4 = hexColor("whatever"); // error!
// Argument of type '"whatever"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"00a0e0"'.
```

Looks good.  The good calls succeed, while the bad calls fail with an error message that is hopefully enough information to help the developer see their problem. Each error message mentions the "closest" valid input.  For completely bad inputs like `"whatever"` it might not be that obvious (`"00a0e0"` is valid, and preserves the `"a"` and `"e"` characters, while replacing the rest with `"0"`, but who knows if a confused developer will understand that), but hopefully it's good enough.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2&ssl=17&ssc=52&pln=17&pc=53#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhAeUC8UDkAGVUA+aCMWuqATIWgMxmoAsVArFQGxUDsVAHFQJxUCCVAISoBhKgBEqAUSoAxKgEMqAIyoBjKgBMqEKgDNUAbgBQJ0JFgJhAewA2VgE4AeACpQEwCADsNAZyg-gewBLTwBzABooABk3eA9vP3lPEABtAF1kKHTI3lj4339AkNDMgCJSgD5kIyha6JTSmy9Q4AALUoz3LwLGKAB+KFyALhq61y6EqAADABIAbxDdCHsoGQBfecXlqAAlNan+i3hrOycdyJT0SIA6W6i0yNm53g25mTzuvzhEAfehqHQ+wqo1q-2+JwcjnKFyuUFu13uj3mL3QUwqxiMqisngCUFallsDkyLg+kwCwTCFQAFK1-uM4p8jhCnM4qgNXGCCacXBUAJTIKqtDGY7G4kB4TL446E+xU0roPDEcjUOilXnGLE44BQEDESVchxy3gCYRiSQyNUa0XakDkfXS05y9DoXS6Z2Wkya3GeCUoKXMo0ms2WqAAelDg3soQArgBbLzaqy6KBmaCoUrG02SUpYIJ+TxWbXyHw+IKhTzyJRNFNWKBgeT2eTxjwrJMp8BpjNByToHPXEVaqCePV+g2yrtZmS8EPhyMx+OeRPJ1NoCdmqc5qB5oeFqDF0vlyvV4C1+uN5vbNsr9OZ9d9gfeu2jh2G+WKgDiMmz6rDEd4UbjBMoCvDtVwVYhP2zXN813fcywrKtoBPOsGybCAW2A5dQPTcD0C-e8vW1TxqHtANSgAd1aeQPAAN2WGc-wAhcl3bcx00o6iIDo+xN23AsixLeCjyQ09UIvVssLY+V0HkdAIF7VB+yMIA)

Answer (score 2):

Your type is simply too complex. You're asking TypeScript to validate against `22^6` possibilities (113,379,904 possible states).